# How to check if a Python dict has a specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

So I want to add the term to the Dict if the term is not yet present in that particular Dict. So if `Dict = {}`, and I do `Dict.update({‘hi’:’hello’})`, the Dict would have the ‘`hi`’ as the key. Now say that I have multiple Dicts, such as `Dict`, `Dict1`, `Dict2`... and so on. And now I want to make it so when I want to add this key:value pair into the Dict, if Dict has it, then it will go automatically to `Dict1`, and if `Dict1` has it, then to `Dict2` and so on.

Right now I am stuck on using `if [key] in Dict`, then like add it to another, but that doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Why are you placing key within a list?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? What relationship do these dicts have to each other? Did you consider putting them into a list, instead of having separate variables?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO ! Please, provide some code so that the community could help you.

Comment: Please show your attempt, expand on "that doesn't seem to work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your dicts inside a list then check if the key in the first dict to move the next one, for example:

```py
# some dicts
dict1 = {'cats': 1, 'dogs': 2, 'fish': 3}
dict2 = {'cow': 4}
dict3 = {}

# add the dicts inside a list
dicts = [dict1, dict2 dict3]

# assume I want to add {'dogs': 2} to my dicts
key = 'dogs'
value = 2

# iterate overall dicts inorder to find a dict doesn't contain the key
for dict in dicts: 
    # this will skip all dicts that contains the key
    # so it automatically will go to the next dict
    if key not in dict: 
        dict.update({key: value})
        # stop updating after finding the next dict
        break
```

Comment: OP says he wants to add key/value pair if the key **is** in the previous dictionary.l

Comment: Umm ^^ wasn’t my point. My point was that there is a series of dicts, then when one has this particular key:value, then the replica would be stored in the other dicts, in order. So say dict1 = {hi:hello}, and another {hi:hello} is submitted, then this {hi:hello} would be stored into dict2, making dict1 and dict2 both have {hi:hello} in them. And if another {hi:hello} is submitted, then it would go into dict3 and so on.

Comment: No problem, so approve the answer.